# Does using 'Auto-Attempt' count towards Open Sesame achievement/trophy?

Tags: achievements, kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

The description for the Open Sesame achievement says: Dispel 50 wards.  When I bring up the Dispel Ward menu I have the option to either 'Dispel' it or 'Auto-Attempt' it.  If I auto-attempt and it works does that count toward the Open Sesame achievement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. Read the last post in this [link](http://www.giantbomb.com/kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning/61-30330/dispel-chests/35-535194/)

Comment: That's how I got the achievement.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes, they do](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYv_KZexP-c#1:30). At about 1:30 in the video, you'll notice one of the tips is actually to use Auto-Attempt to make things go quicker.